# Adjectival form of "type"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjectival form of the word "type" that means "having to do with types"?  The obvious adjectives "typical" and "typic" mean something different (roughly, "characteristic").

Context: In [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) I am looking for an adjective to modify "equality" to indicate that I am talking about the equality type rather than the definitional/judgmental equality.  For this reason, using "type" attributively won't work either, because "type equality" is established to mean equality *of* types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *typal*.

Comment: Thanks!  Apparently one of its definitions is the same as "typical", but it also has the meaning I want, and it's less common so it will be less likely to automatically suggest the wrong meaning to a reader.